Midnight Commander on Win 10, Running under ConEmu, disabling 256 support
Using Win10 -> Cmder -> Mc
Hide panels - Ctrl - O (working well in Far)
I got "Running under ConEmu, disabling 256 support" that lock the screen, I cannot use command line in this case (Ok in Far).
Is the some way how to fix this? I usually hide panels to use CLI

